# Emoticons in chat application

Tags: android, emoji, emotion

I have imported [this](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) library in my project and using the smileys from it,but I am not able to reproduce the smileys on other users handset.
it shows some numbers on other end.
what might be the reason

Receiver gets this

```
03-25 13:10:39.148: I/user1(1774): bhavikߘĀ
03-25 13:11:28.028: I/user1(1774): bhavikߘ��
```

when Sender sends this

```
03-25 13:10:46.928: I/user2(1774): sanket
03-25 13:10:52.424: I/user2(1774): sanket
```

Comment: I get some numbers as 15431 5431

Comment: show you code display smileys (on textview)

Comment: public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        EmojiconsFragment.input(messageText, emojicon);    
    }

Comment: code shows the smileys properly on sender side but on receiver side it shows some numbers

Comment: please show more code

Comment: this is the only code I have used for displaying the smileys

Comment: ok did you use com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView textview for display smileys ??

Comment: yes I used the com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconTextView textview

Comment: ok than you have to debug your program, without code i can't do any thing :)

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to share emoticons you need to embed a unicode character into the string.

For example if you want to add a smiley to a string you could use the following:

```
String helloSmiley = "Hello \uD83D\uDE01";
```

You can find a table of emoji characters [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm).

Comment: I tried encoding but still not working
I am storing the msg sent by 1st user in database and then pulling the same from other users handset